# Batch Class Not Able To Send Email To Contacts

Tags: apex, batch, controller, scheduled-apex

Here is my batch class I am trying to send email to contact.Made may efforts to know problem.In this I am getting value after the query in debug log but still it is not able to send email to record which is filtered in query.

BATCH CLASS:

```
global class BatchWishes implements Database.Batchable<Contact> {

     global Iterable<Contact> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

     list<Contact> sq=[select name,Email, Birthdate from Contact where Birthdate =: date.today() And Email!=null];
     system.debug('******'+sq);
     return sq;
     }

     global  void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> lst){
  list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mail = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
          for(Contact c: lst){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage objEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            list<string> toadd=new list<string>();
            toadd.add(c.Email);
            system.debug('*****'+c.Email);
            objEmail.settoaddresses(toadd);
            system.debug('*****'+toadd);
            objEmail.setsubject('birthday wishes');
            objEmail.setplaintextbody('happy birthday '+c.Firstname);
            mail.add(objEmail);            
          }           
   Messaging.SendEmailResult[]  result =Messaging.sendEmail(mail);
      } 

     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
     System.debug(BC);
     }
}
```

Scheduler:

```
global class BirthdayNameOptions implements Schedulable{

global   void execute(SchedulableContext dc){

  BatchWishes bth=new BatchWishes ();

    Database.executeBatch(bth);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question with more information.  Are you receiving any errors? What is stopping you from sending the email?  How many records are you trying to do this for? Why don't you just use a workflow rule?

Comment: No I am not receiving any erroe just no response is here

Comment: I have few records only around 100

Comment: So what appears in the SendEmailResult list?  Are you not able to edit your question?  You still haven't answered the question about the workflow rules.

Comment: if you are in SB then check `email deliverability`.

Comment: I want to email my contacts on their birth day so it is not possible with the workflow.I think

Comment: And the help article doesn't work for you?  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181218

Comment: I want to go for batch class.Not for workflow. Batch class is easy process I think

Comment: Are you incapable of answering question?

Comment: Almost never implement a solution via code when it can be done declarative.

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating over the Messaging.SendEmailResult[] `result` collection. [SendEmailResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_sendemailresult.htm) includes a `isSuccess()` method. If this is false you should progress to looking at the SendEmailError records returned by `getErrors()`.

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult[]  results = Messaging.sendEmail(mail);
for(Messaging.SendEmailResult sr : results) {
    System.assert(sr.isSuccess(), 'Send Email failed: ' + sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
}
```

Failing that, check the debug log for clues. If the transaction gets rolled back the emails won't get sent.

Double check that *Setup > Administration Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability* has "Access to Send Email (All Email Services)" set to "All email"

Consider setting the second parameter of [`Messaging.sendEmail(emails, allOrNothing)`](http://sendEmail(emails,%20allOrNothing)) to `false`. That way some emails my still get sent even if there are problems.

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult[]  results = Messaging.sendEmail(mail, false);
```